# listof{}{} spacing

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I'm creating a longish document with lots of diagrams, examples, definition etc. and with indexes of them all, but I'm having trouble with the formatting of the lists. - Sorry, I have no proper example code, as I suspect it will be rather long to show the effect. Here are some fragments (I hope this is enough):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}

...

\newfloat{diag}{htbp}{dia}[section]
\floatname{diag}{Diagram}

\begin{document}
    \listof{diag}{Figures}
...
        \begin{diag}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt,label=below:0] (0) at (0,0) {};
                \draw[-stealth] (0.center)++(0,.45)++(-120:.35) arc (240:-60:.35);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{The Category $\mathbb{1}$}
            \label{dia:Category1}
        \end{diag}

...

\end{document}
```

What I get looks like:

[image: List of diagrams]

How can I better separate the numbering from the text in the list?

***Edit:***

A minimal working example (credits to leandriis):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{float} 
\newfloat{diag}{htbp}{dia}[section] 
\floatname{diag}{Diagram} 
\begin{document} 
    \listof{diag}{Figures} 
    \setcounter{section}{16} 
    \section{text} 
    \begin{diag}[H] 
        \caption{caption text here} 
    \end{diag} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: A MWE to reproduce the issue would be: `\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{diag}{htbp}{dia}[section]
\floatname{diag}{Diagram}

\begin{document}
    \listof{diag}{Figures}
\setcounter{section}{16}
\section{text}
        \begin{diag}[H]
            \caption{caption text here}
        \end{diag}

\end{document}`.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks! I'll incorporate it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{float} 
\newfloat{diag}{htbp}{dia}[section] 
\floatname{diag}{Diagram} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\listof}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
    \@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}% <-------  replaced 2.3em with 3em here
    \float@listhead{#2}%
    \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
      \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
    \endgroup}}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
    \listof{diag}{Figures} 
    \setcounter{section}{16} 
    \section{text} 
    \begin{diag}[H] 
        \caption{caption text here} 
    \end{diag} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Intriguing - it does look quite daunting, but as long as it works. Thanks!